# Questions on use of CCDT to connect to IBM MQ

Tags: java, ibm-mq

I am looking for HA/LB solution for my java (spring-boot) application doing pub/sub messages through IBM MQ and have following questions on CCDT

1. given a queue manager cluster of 2 QMs, naming QM1 and QM2, can my application use CCDT to achieve some kind of HA? that is defined both QM1 & QM2 in CCDT and if QM1 fails, application will automatically switch to QM2. the tricky part is QM1/2 have different names and in application property you can specify only one QM name. I found a document about [Queue manager groups](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.1?topic=table-queue-manager-groups-in-ccdt), is this right way to go?
2. how to achieve LB? say there is two instances of the application, and they are able to connect to different QMs by default
3. I understand that JSON format CCDT was introduced in IBM MQ after version 9.1.2. Since the CCDT file is for client-side usage, I wonder if I can use JSON format CCDT in a java application with latest version MQ library (v9.3.0) to connect to an earlier version of IBM MQ server (v9.1.0). provided that latest version MQ library has no problem connecting to v9.1.0 with connection properties set

Comment: Queue manger group is how you world get around the two different names.   9.3 will not have a problem connecting to 9.1.  I would suggest you just have one channel entry in the json CCDT with two connection names listed.   Use one file for each application instance with the connection name order reversed so that each app instance prefers one queue manager of the other.   You then have a problem of how to fail the app server back once your queue manager recovers from a failure.

Comment: One suggest is to run two instances of the app on each server each configured only to connect to one queue manager.   Each app server will have an instance pointed to each queue manager.  In this way if a queue manager crashes you will have two instances connected to the remaining queue manger and two instances trying to reconnect to the crashed queue manager.   When the queue manger recovers the app instances will reconnect. Similarly if one app server crashes you will still have an instance connected to each queue manger.

Comment: If you migrate your queue manger to 9.2 or later you could look at uniform clusters which will dynamically handle keeping the available clients balanced across the available queue managers.

Comment: @JoshMc in uniform cluster, can a SUB be shared across QMs? in queue manager cluster, I have to define a cluster local queue in each QM and set it as SUB dest. how to do that with uniform cluster?

Comment: @JoshMc this seems more of a problem for the topic-sub application. is there any config similar to "aged timeout"? which will discard established connection in a given interval

Comment: The only thing close to what you mention may be DISCINT on the SVRCONN, but that won't disconnect a connection unless it is idle.  You can cluster studies in a uniform cluster or they could be a member of a larger overlapping cluster.

Comment: @JoshMc noted, tons of thanks for your advise